# Parsing through Vectors

Tags: c++11, vector

I am new and learning C++ using the Programming Principles ... book by Bjarne Stroustrup. I am working on one problem and can't figure out how to make my code work. I know the issue is with `if (words[i]==bad[0, bad.size() - 1])` in particular `bad.size() - 1])`

I am trying to out put all words in the words vector except display a bleep instead of any words from the words vector that match any of the words in the bad vector. So I need to know if words[i] matches any of the values in the bad vector.

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

int main()  
{
vector<string> words; //declare Vector
vector<string> bad = {"idiot", "stupid"};

//Read words into Vector
for(string temp; cin >> temp;)
        words.push_back(temp);
cout << "Number of words currently entered "
    << words.size() << '\n';

//sort the words
sort(words);

//read out words
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    if (i==0 || words[i-1]!= words[i])
        if (words[i]==bad[0, bad.size() - 1])
        cout << "Bleep!\n";
        else
        cout << words[i] << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bad[0, bad.size() - 1]` is not valid C++ syntax. It's probably from Pascal or something like this. It should _probably_ be `bad[0][bad.size() - 1]`, but I think this is not what you want because it will run out of bounds.

Comment: I understand that how would be the correct way to say ... check all entries from start to finish, is where I'm stuck at.

Comment: @ForceBru It is completely valid syntax. Check comma operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through all of the entries in the `bad` vector for each entry in the `words` vector. Something like this:

```
for(const string& word : words)
{
    bool foundBadWord = false;
    for(const string& badWord : bad)
    {
        if(0 == word.compare(badWord))
        {
            foundBadWord = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(foundBadWord)
    {
        cout << "Bleep!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << word << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am positive that the above will work.... Will take me a little while to see what is  happening with all that code, only on Chapter 3 lol. I may have got ahead of my self with this exercise. But thanks very much sir!!